# Text selection index was clamped (-1->0) to remain in bounds. This may not be your fault, as some keyboards may select outside of bounds

Tags: flutter

I have lock screen with pininput text field.My requirement is, the Ok button should be enabled only when 4 digits are entered,else the button should be disabled. I used onchanged property of text field but the above error occurs.The code i used is shared along with this...

```
PinInputTextField(
                      pinLength: 4,
                      inputFormatter: [
                        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      //decoration: BoxTightDecoration(),
                      controller: lockScreenController,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      onChanged: (pin) {
                        if (pin.length == 4) {
                          setState(() {
                            this.isButtonEnabled = true;
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            this.isButtonEnabled = false;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: width * 0.15,
                    height: height * 0.13,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      //ok button
                      color: Color(0xfff6dd34),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      onPressed: !isButtonEnabled
                          ? null
                          : () {
                              //save 4 digit pin
                            },
                      child: Text("ok",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: width * 0.028,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Full code given below

```
class ResetLockScreenPassword extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ResetLockScreenPasswordState createState() =>
      _ResetLockScreenPasswordState();
}

class _ResetLockScreenPasswordState extends State<ResetLockScreenPassword> {
  final _resetLockScreenPassword = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool isButtonEnabled = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.53;

    return Dialog(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: _buildChild(context, width, height),
    );
  }

 

  _buildChild(BuildContext context, width, height) {
    final TextEditingController lockScreenController = TextEditingController();
    return Form(
      key: _resetLockScreenPassword,
      child: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
        ),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Set Lock Screen Password ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: height * 0.1,
                          color: Color(0xfff6dd34),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: width * 0.5,
                    child: PinInputTextField(
                      pinLength: 4,
                      inputFormatter: [
                        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                      ],
                      //decoration: BoxTightDecoration(),
                      controller: lockScreenController,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      onChanged: (pin) {
                        if (pin.length == 4) {
                          setState(() {
                            this.isButtonEnabled = true;
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            this.isButtonEnabled = false;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: width * 0.15,
                    height: height * 0.13,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      //ok button
                      color: Color(0xfff6dd34),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      onPressed: !isButtonEnabled
                          ? null
                          : () {
                              //save 4 digit pin
                            },
                      child: Text("ok",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: width * 0.028,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
          Positioned(
            //cross button
            right: 10,
            top: 10,
            child: Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child:
                    Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.black, size: width * 0.04),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Anoop, **give me the link for the flutter package**. I guess, we might get something important after reading it again. Or confirm, if this is this package which you're using: https://pub.dev/packages/pin_input_text_field?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [pin_input_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_input_text_field), then you might want to consider `pin` in your `onChanged()` method. Since `pin` is String only, we can use it's length, and perform your operation.

```
onChanged: (String pin){
  if(pin.length == 4){
    setState(() => this.isButtonEnabled = true);
  }else{
    setState(() => this.isButtonEnabled = false);
  }
}
```

Check this out, and let me know if that works out for you :)

Comment: That is strange. Ok @anoop tell me what happens when you remove complete code inside the `onChanged`? Are you able to input all 4 digits?

Comment: Yes ,I'm using the same package.I did edit my code as you suggested but now the issue I found is that I couldn't enter the second digit.When I Comment the onChanged property of pin_entry_text_field , I could enter 4 digits but didn't met my requirement.

Comment: Hey @anoop, just checking you have added `PinEditingController` and not `TextEditingController` to your `PinInputTextField` controller. We must take every precautions before reaching to the final stage :)

Comment: I guess this is where you are making mistake, cos in the docs, it is written to have `PinEditingController` rather than `TextEditingController` in the controller field. Please go ahead and read that. this might give you some clarity

Comment: From version 2.0.0 it is written  "Remove: remove the PinEditingController class, just simply use TextEditingController".thats why  I used  TextEditingController